# no git repository but all the git stuff is there

Tags: git

after having moved my repositories from one disk to another today I got the following answer for all the repositories:

```
$ git status 
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Now, all my git stuff is there in the repository:

```
$ ls -al
total 8
drwx------ 1 luca luca    0 2011-12-12 10:36 .
drwx------ 1 luca luca 4096 2012-01-02 09:49 ..
drwx------ 1 luca luca 4096 2011-12-12 10:36 .git
drwx------ 1 luca luca    0 2011-12-12 10:36 img
$ du -hs .git/*
0       .git/branches
0       .git/hooks
0       .git/info
12K     .git/logs
58K     .git/objects
0       .git/refs
```

So I guess git is somehow confused about something, maybe a permission that is not correct. Any idea about how to restore all my repositories history?

Comment: What operating system? If you're on Linux, the last few lines of `strace git status` will give you the answer.

Comment: Well, this is the output: `stat(".git", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
access(".git/objects", X_OK)            = 0
access(".git/refs", X_OK)               = 0
lstat(".git/HEAD", 0x7fffd0a72f90)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("./objects", X_OK)               = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
` and the first .git/objects is succesfull, the others no.

Answer (score 2):

See if there is a `HEAD` file under .git and also there are proper permissions on it.

Comment: Effectively it is missing HEAD, config, and description. Is there a way to restore them?

Comment: I am missing also refs/heads (I mean the directory is empty). On the other hand, the remote refs has its head (but it is not the head I want).

Comment: @fluca1978 - Try doing a `git init` again (backup!)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an `index` file, which means your repository is in a "bare" state.

Try:

```
git branch
```

to see the list of available branches, then:

```
git checkout thebranch
```

Comment: I guess the problem is more critical, since I cannot run any git command, having always the error of "Not a git repository"

Comment: Try and `GIT_DIR=path/to/.git git branch`, does anything turn up?